# Notepad++ missing run commands

Tags: notepad++

I uncommented the shortcuts.xml code  to run in IE ... but I still don't see the run options when I run NotePad++. Is there something else that I need to do?  I'm new to notepad ++.
Thanks!

Comment: Is your Notepad++ up-to-date and can you post a screenshot of what you're seeing instead?

Answer (score 1):

This is what the default Run menu looks like:

[image]

The shortcut for "Launch in IE" is
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>.

In case your version of the file
`C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\shortcuts.xml`
was corrupted, here is my default version of it:

```
<NotepadPlus>
    <InternalCommands />
    <Macros>
        <Macro name="Trim Trailing Space and Save" Ctrl="no" Alt="yes" Shift="yes" Key="83">
            <Action type="2" message="0" wParam="42024" lParam="0" sParam="" />
            <Action type="2" message="0" wParam="41006" lParam="0" sParam="" />
        </Macro>
    </Macros>
    <UserDefinedCommands>
        <Command name="Launch in Firefox" Ctrl="yes" Alt="yes" Shift="yes" Key="88">firefox &quot;$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)&quot;</Command>
        <Command name="Launch in IE" Ctrl="yes" Alt="yes" Shift="yes" Key="73">iexplore &quot;$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)&quot;</Command>
        <Command name="Launch in Chrome" Ctrl="yes" Alt="yes" Shift="yes" Key="82">chrome &quot;$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)&quot;</Command>
        <Command name="Launch in Safari" Ctrl="yes" Alt="yes" Shift="yes" Key="65">safari &quot;$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)&quot;</Command>
        <Command name="Get php help" Ctrl="no" Alt="yes" Shift="no" Key="112">http://www.php.net/$(CURRENT_WORD)</Command>
        <Command name="Wikipedia Search" Ctrl="no" Alt="yes" Shift="no" Key="114">https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Search?search=$(CURRENT_WORD)</Command>
        <Command name="Open file in another instance" Ctrl="no" Alt="yes" Shift="no" Key="117">$(NPP_FULL_FILE_PATH) $(CURRENT_WORD) -nosession -multiInst</Command>
        <Command name="Send via Outlook" Ctrl="yes" Alt="yes" Shift="yes" Key="79">outlook /a &quot;$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)&quot;</Command>
    </UserDefinedCommands>
    <PluginCommands />
    <ScintillaKeys />
</NotepadPlus>
```